# GitLabCI deploy expressjs app dont finish the deploy stage

Tags: node.js, docker, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

just finished the ci cd build at gitlab, and i'm using a nodejs image with docker to build, and in the last step of deploy, the log show that is running `yarn dev` fine but the gitlab ci has a 1 hour limit of running pipeline.

What i need to do to run de expressjs app and finish the pipeline execution without stopping the app ?

I know that with docker i can ran with the detached option, but there is any way to do without build the app docker image ?

CICD Log with the app running:

[image: log]

```
image: node:12.18.1

stages:
 - build
 - test
 - deploy

before_script:
 - yarn

build-min-code:
 stage: build
 script:
   - yarn

deploy-staging:
 stage: deploy
 script:
   - yarn dev
 only:
   - dev
```

Like this works fine, but in one hour the timeout will finish the runner execution.

Answer (score 0):

Bump up the timeout. The default is 60 minutes: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#timeout

Note: on the gitlab-runner - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#set-maximum-job-timeout-for-a-runner

Comment: There isnt a correct way to deploy without docker ? And in prod ?